# Definite integral $\int_0^92\sqrt x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble trying to solve this definite integral: $$\int_0^92\sqrt x\,\mathrm dx.$$

I already made this:
[image]

But I don't know how to proceed with this Riemann Summation.
(I cant solve it using FTC, only Riemann Summation).

Comment: Looks like a massive overkill. Do you absolutely have to solve the integral this way?

Comment: Yep, the exercise explicitly says "Find the area of the following functions limited by the interval using Riemann Summation", and then there is y = 2*sqrt(x), [0, 9].

Comment: Then you should include that detail in your question..

Comment: I guess the purpose of this exercise is mostly to see *what is going on* with Reimann Sums and how they can be calculated if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing says your partition has to be evenly spaced.  Set your samples at $x_i^* = (3i/n)^2$.  Your integrand is $f(x) = 2\sqrt{x}$, so $f(x_i^*) = 6i/n$, which you should find easier to sum.